# Generic method to get an attribute from a member of a type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, attributes

I created a convenience method that uses generics to retrieve an attribute applied to a type:

```
/// <summary>
/// Return an attribute from the provided type if it exists on that type.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type whose attribute <typeparamref name="TAttType"/> 
/// will be returned if it exists on that type.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TAttType">The type of attribute that will be retrieved
/// on <typeparamref name="T"/> if it exists.</typeparam>
/// <returns>Return the attribute with type <typeparamref name="TAttType"/>, 
/// if it exists, from target type <typeparamref name="T"/> or else
/// return null.</returns>
public static TAttType GetAttribute<T, TAttType>() where TAttType:Attribute 
    => (TAttType) typeof(T).GetCustomAttribute(typeof(TAttType), false);
```

This only works for attributes on types though.  I.e. if I have this attribute:

```
public class VehicleAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Color { get; }
    public int NumWheels { get; }

    public VehicleAttribute(string color, int numWheels)
    {
        Color = color;
        NumWheels = numWheels;
    }
}
```

I can do this:

```
[Vehicle("Yellow", 6)]
public class Bus { }
```

And then this:

```
var att = ReflectionTools.GetAttribute<Bus, VehicleAttribute>();
```

But if I have a property like this (not that it makes sense, but just for demo purposes):

```
[Vehicle("Blue", 5)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

I want to be able to use a similar approach.  Is there a way I can use generics to facilitate the retrieval of an attribute from *any* `System.Reflection.MemberInfo`, not just `System.Type`?

Comment: That should be doable using expressions.

Comment: @thehennyy -- Not one of my strong suits presently.  Would you mind helping me out?

Comment: You mean like the generic methods here: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/reflection/CustomAttributeExtensions.cs? They've been around for a while and intellisense should pull them in

Comment: Oh I think I see what you mean...something like thehennyy's answer below. Leaving my other comment anyways. Note that if you need inherited attributes that his solution won't work on properties (or events) as you have to call `Attribute.GetCustomAttributes` in those instances

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `MemberExpression` to specify the member you want to get the attribute from. Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

public class VehicleAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Color { get; }
    public int NumWheels { get; }

    public VehicleAttribute(string color, int numWheels)
    {
        Color = color;
        NumWheels = numWheels;
    }
}

[Vehicle("Yellow", 6)]
public class Bus
{ 

    [Vehicle("Blue", 5)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Test<Bus, VehicleAttribute>((x) => x.Name).Color);
    }

    static U Test<T, U>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr) where U : Attribute
    {
        if(!(expr.Body is MemberExpression memberExpr))
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("expr");
        }
        return (U)memberExpr.Member.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(U), false);
    }
}
```